# How find this value of $x,a$

Tags: calculus

let $0<a<1$,and such
$$\log_{a}{x}+3\log_{x}{a}-\log_{x}{y}=3$$
and $y_{max}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$,
Find the $a,x$

My try: since
$$\dfrac{1}{\log_{x}{a}}+3\log_{x}{a}-\log_{x}{y}=3$$
$$\dfrac{1}{\log_{x}{a}}=\log_{x}{(\dfrac{x^3\cdot y}{a^3})}$$

Then I can't,and I think this problem have nice methods.Thank you

Comment: [logic] is not for $\log$'ic related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 < x < 1$, $y$ is maximum when $\log_x y$ is a minimum.

So we look for the minimum of $\log_a x + 3\log_x a - 3$.  Clearly this is when $\log_a x = \sqrt3$, and the minimum value is $2\sqrt3-3$.

Thus $2\sqrt3-3 = \log_x {y_{max}} = \log_x{\frac{\sqrt2}4}$.  Solving this gives $x=2^{-\frac{3}{2 \left(-3+2 \sqrt{3}\right)}} \approx 0.106$.

Then $\log_a x = \sqrt3$ gives $a=2^{\frac{1}{2 \left(-2+\sqrt{3}\right)}} \approx 0.274$.

---

OTOH, if $x > 1$, $\log_a x$ is negative, and the maximum is when $\log_a x = -\sqrt3$, with a maximum value of $-3-2\sqrt3$.

Solving $\log_x{\frac{\sqrt2}4}=-3-2\sqrt3$, we get $x=2^{\frac{3}{2 \left(3+2 \sqrt{3}\right)}} \approx 1.17$, and again from $\log_a x = -\sqrt3$, we get $a = 2^{-\frac{1}{2 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}} \approx 0.911$